# Eclipse CDT: Dynamic Printf feature not working

Tags: c, gdb, mingw, eclipse-cdt

During Debug mode, if we add Dynamic Printf breakpoint; Eclipse CDT adds an entry in the 'Breakpoints' view but it doesn't display content for dynamic printf on the Console.

Tried both checking and unchecking 'Allocate console (necessary for input)' under 'Common' tab in Debug Configurations, but Dynamic Printf isn't working.

Environment: Eclipse CDT (Oxygen) and GNU gdb (GDB) 7.6.1 running on Windows 7 64-bit.

If we hover over Dynamic Printf breakpoint, it shows below warning:

[image]

Any inputs to get Dynamic Printf feature working on Eclipse CDT?

Comment: Probably optimizer get rid of  your code and that line does not exists. Try compiling with `-O0` option

Comment: @LPs No luck as the code is already being built by internal builder that uses option -O0.

Comment: 16:27:28 **** Rebuild of configuration Debug for project DynamicPrintf ****
Info: Internal Builder is used for build
gcc -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -o "src\\DynamicPrintf.o" "..\\src\\DynamicPrintf.c" 
gcc -o DynamicPrintf.exe "src\\DynamicPrintf.o"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CDT only support Dynamic Printf breakpoints from GDB 7.7 and later.

Have a look at the [feature bugzilla](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=400628) for the details, but the short story is GDB 7.5 and 7.6 had too many bugs for CDT to reasonably support.

Comment: PS The error message could be more helpful. I'll look into that.

Comment: I changed the warning message to say `Breakpoint installation failed: Dynamic-Printf usage in CDT requires GDB 7.7 or later`. WDYT? Would that have solved your problem faster. Please feel free to comment in: https://git.eclipse.org/r/#/c/92511

Comment: Bravo! Appreciate all your efforts @Jonah. Configured Eclipse CDT (Oxygen) with latest available mingw-w64 [GNU gdb (GDB) 7.11.1] and 'Dynamic Printf' feature works like a charm!